# Including custom stylus files in to Layout (Vuepress 1.x)

Tags: vuepress

Vuepress documentation is very poor, simple things is so complicated... In my case i've created my custom theme, with the following file tree:

[image]

What's the correct way to include my stylus files in to a global Layout.vue? I can include styles this way:

```
<style lang="stylus">
@import '../styles/index.styl'
</style>
```

Is this a right approach? Also i experience the issues with the correct paths.

Answer (score 0):

I just gave up on Vuepress (it's not production ready in my opinion) and used Nuxt generate instead.